# How to Lag in Different Time Periods?

Tags: stata

I am using a large Panel data covering the years 1970 to 2002. One of the variables has an observation for the years 1985, 1995, 1999 and 2002. The variable looks as follows:

```
     +-------------------------+
     | country   year   groups |
     |-------------------------|
  1. | Germany   1985        5 |
  2. | Germany   1995       10 |
  3. | Germany   1997        . |
  4. | Germany   1998        . |
  5. | Germany   1999       20 |
     +-------------------------+
```

My intention is to lag the Groups variable by its next Observation. I have created a dummy showing 1 for These time periods, but I don't know how to take the next step. What can I do to lag this Group variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not entirely clear to me whether you want groups to represent the value of the next or of the previous year. Anyhow, the syntax for this is fairly simple if you have each country/year only once in the dataset:

```
bysort country year: replace groups=groups[_n-1] //for the previous observation 
bysort country year: replace groups=groups[_n+1] //for the next observation
```

I am not sure why are you doing this, but maybe you want to get rid of the missing values. In that case take a look at [this post](http://www.stata.com/support/faqs/data-management/replacing-missing-values/) or on `carryforward` from ssc.

Comment: My Intention is to create an Instrument using [_n-1]. When I run the Regression, Stata considers only the time periods 1985, 1995, 1999 and 2002. Your Approach could work, but only if I drop every other year other than These four. However if I do this, the Observation from 2002 moves to the next Country. I suppose I could create a duplicate and manually remove the Observation for 2002, then lag it.

Comment: you could avoid moving it to another country by adding bysort country year before, like: bysort country year: groups=groups[_n-1] I will also edit my answer.